# Access is converting a Linked Sharepoint List text column into an AutoID field

Tags: database, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So a small bit of weirdness today: I have a Sharepoint list linked to my Access database.  At the time of linking, Access created an Autonumber "ID" column.  This is good.

I went ahead and added a text column for comments to the list on the Sharepoint end, but this new column was not reflected in the linked Access table.  In an attempt to remedy this, I removed and re-linked the Sharepoint list to my Access database.  A few things have happended:

-Access did not create an Autonumber "ID" column for the new, re-linked table

-Access now recognizes my new "Comments" column, but it overwrote all of my text data with Autonumbers (as if it had converted my "Comments" column into an Autonumber column, while still keeping it as Type = "Text").

I attempted to re-link the table again, but the same thing happened.  I would like to achieve the following behavior:

-Have Access generate the Autonumber ID column upon linking, like it did originally

-Have Access properly link to the text data in the new "Comments" column on my Sharepoint list, instead filling it with Autonumbers.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: there was an issue with the Caching of Sharepoint lists in Access.  I went ahead and set Sharepoint Caching to "Never" under Options -> Current Database, and now my list is updating as it should.

Thanks anyway!